# Prove that for $ f(x+2\cdot\pi)=f(x), x \in \mathbb{R} $, there exists $ x_0 $ so $ f(x_0+\pi)=f(x_0) $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Prove that for $ f(x+2\cdot\pi)=f(x), x \in \mathbb{R} $, there exists $ x_0 $ so $ f(x_0+\pi)=f(x_0) $. 
This is supposed to be question about continuity, but I’m not sure exactly what they mean, perhaps I misunderstood some concept along the way.

Comment: " This is supposed to be question about continuity " Is $f$ assumed to be continuous? It seems an important assumption, but you do not make it explicit. The statement is false for arbitrary functions, so some additional hypotheses to what you wrote are needed.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $f$ is continuous. Then $$h:[0,\pi]\to \mathbb{R}, x\to h(x)=f(x+\pi)-f(x),$$ is continuous on $[0,\pi].$ It is

$$h(0)=f(\pi)-f(0)$$ and

$$h(\pi)=f(2\pi)-f(\pi)=f(0)-f(\pi).$$

If $f(0)=f(\pi)$ we are done. If not, then $h(0)$ and $h(\pi)$ have different signs. Then applying Bolzano's theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) we get that there exists $x_0\in(0,\pi)$ such that $h(x_0)=0.$ That is, $f(x_0+\pi)=f(x_0).$

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the intermediate value theorem to get this done.

Look at the function $g(x)=f(x+\pi)-f(x)$. At specific values: $g(\pi)=f(2\pi)-f(\pi)=f(0)-f(\pi)=-g(0)$. At $0$ we have a value of $g(0)$ and at $\pi$ we have a value of $-g(0)$. The intermediate value theorem then says we'll have a point in $c\in(0,\pi)$ such that $g(c)=0$. Then $f(c)=f(c+\pi)$.